# FFMPEG convert from mp3 to WAV invalid arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, ffmpeg

My command is: -i testfile.mp3 out.wav

Just simple convert on my website from one format to other, without any bitrates etc. But I have an error while trying convert

```
[NULL @ 0x81a960] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'output/out.wav'
main.js:194 output/out.wav: Invalid argument
main.js:192 exit(1) called
```

```
// input file params
var fileName;
var fileBuffer;

function timeToSeconds(time) {
    var parts = time.split(":");
    return parseFloat(parts[0]) * 60 * 60 + parseFloat(parts[1]) * 60 + parseFloat(parts[2]) + parseFloat("0." + parts[3]);
}

// create ffmpeg worker
var ffmpegWorker = getFFMPEGWorker();
var ffmpegRunning = false;

$('#convert').click(function() {
    // terminate existing worker
    if (ffmpegRunning) {
        ffmpegWorker.terminate();
        ffmpegWorker = getFFMPEGWorker();
    }
    ffmpegRunning = true;

    // display converting animation
    $("#converting").show();
    $("#error").hide();

    // hide download div
    $("#download").hide();

    // change download file name
    var fileNameExt = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    var outFileName = fileName.substr(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.')) + "." + getOutFormat();
    $("#downloadLink").attr("download", outFileName);
    $("#downloadLink").text(outFileName);

    var arguments = [];
    arguments.push('-i');
    arguments.push(fileName);
    switch (getOutFormat()) {
        case "mp3":
            arguments.push("-acodec");
            arguments.push("lib lame");
            arguments.push("out.mp3");
            break;
        case "ogg":
            arguments.push("-acodec");
            arguments.push("libvorbis");
            arguments.push("out.ogg");
            break;
        case "aac":
            arguments.push("-acodec");
            arguments.push("libfdk_aac");
            arguments.push("out.mp4");
            break;
        case "wma":
            arguments.push("-acodec");
            arguments.push("wmav1");
            arguments.push("out.asf");
            break;
        case "wav":
            arguments.push("out.wav");
            break;
    }

    ffmpegWorker.postMessage({
        type: "command",
        arguments: arguments,
        files: [
            {
                "name": fileName,
                "buffer": fileBuffer
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Build of FFMPEG is: `ffmpeg version git-2013-11-21-e18f8f6 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers`

Maybe someone has a fresh FFMPEG.js build?

Im trying to find some new build's but all to no avail.

Comment: Does the `output` directory exist?

Comment: output is going to href link  $("#downloadLink").attr('href', src);

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you are trying to use.

Comment: can you check this pls

Comment: The issue most likely is that there is no `output` subdirectory in the current working directory. FFmpeg does not create output folders.

Comment: @kesh there is no output subdirectory, there going to ahref, so I can download it from browser

Comment: Well ,`"output/out.wav"` indicates there is... But, nonetheless, with fresh eyes I looked at your post and you can add `-c:a pcm_s16le` (which shouldn't be needed as it is the default). As for checking your FFmpeg, run `ffmpeg -h muxer=wav` and if it doesn't know what it is that would be the issue but I highly doubt that.

Comment: @kesh after `ffmpeg -h muxer=wav` returned `Unknown format 'wav'.`

Comment: you need to update your FFmpeg. 2013 is an ancient old. I tested with the latest 5.1.2 build and it comes with the wav muxer. (still surprised that yours don't have it though. such a basic codec)

Comment: And how I can update my FFmpeg? Cause I get this as example with already done ffmpeg.js file. Should I try from ./configure to build new one? Or how?

Comment: ffmpeg.org would be a good place to start... I have no idea what your setup is. So you need to do your own research. If you're capable of building it from source, thats not a bad option.